# Any apparent security concern or downside of a browser-based client?

Tags: web-services, rest, design-patterns, web-applications

I am tasked with a web application project involving a lot of dynamic design.

I am going to build a RESTful API with Node.js with token-based authentication, and initially I thought about building another Node.js application for web-based UI, but now that I have a basic design of the API, I was wondering if it is feasible to implement all of the UI logic with JavaScript on the browser?

It would involve a HTML page, which has JavaScript that will GET/POST data from the API, and update the DOM accordingly, furthermore, I would save authentication token in cookie, and the JavaScript in browser would do everything ranging from login to updating/deleting/creating all kinds of data through the RESTful API.

I haven't heard anything quite like this, is there any security concerns? Off the top of my head, the API server would get tremendous amount of requests if attacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the amount of traffic or code, the security concern is the same.

- Is anything sensitive being sent to the browser?
- Is any request to the server not being validated?

That's pretty much the extent of the security.  Any attacker can craft any bombardment of requests to any API, regardless of how complex the client-side code for the application is.

Assume that client-side code might not execute at all.  Assume that you have no control over the client-side code.  Assume that every request reaching the API must be validated.  Assume that any input coming to the API can't be trusted.  Etc.

Basically there are no *additional* security concerns which wouldn't exist in any of the simplest web applications.